# How do I create a virtual column equal to the difference between two previous values of another column in peewee?

Tags: peewee

I thought this should be fairly easy to implement but I've tried several approaches without success. This is my latest try.

The Ts model below represents a time-series of numbers and the goal is to calculate the difference between the count in any two rows of the table.

The self-contained code listed below produces the following correct output:

```
SELECT "t1"."date", "t1"."count", ("t1"."count" - LAG("t1"."count", 1) 
OVER (ORDER BY "t1"."date")) AS "diff" FROM "ts" AS "t1"
(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 101, None)
(datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), 104, 3)
(datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), 109, 5)
(datetime.date(2020, 1, 4), 116, 7)
```

However, when the line:

```
return (self.count - fn.LAG(self.count, 1)
```

is changed to:

```
return (fn.LAG(self.count, 0) - fn.LAG(self.count, 1)
```

the code fails with this error:

```
peewee.OperationalError: misuse of window function LAG()
```

Ideally the solution would allow specifying the two rows (0 and 1 in this example) at runtime.

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import date
from peewee import *
from playhouse.hybrid import *

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Ts(BaseModel):
    date = DateField()
    count = IntegerField()

    @hybrid_property
    def diff(self):
        return None

    @diff.expression
    def diff(self):
        return (fn.LAG(self.count, 0).over(order_by=[self.date])
                -
                fn.LAG(self.count, 1).over(order_by=[self.date])
        ).alias('diff')

db.connect()
Ts.drop_table()
db.create_tables([Ts])

for i in range(1,5):
    ts = Ts(date=date(2020,1,i), count=100+i**2)
    ts.save()

q = Ts.select(Ts.date, Ts.count, Ts.diff)
print(q)
[print(t) for t in q.tuples()]
```

UPDATE:

Doh! The problem is that the window has to be explicitly specified for both LAG invocations like this:

```
(fn.LAG(self.count, 0).over(order_by=[self.date])
 -
 fn.LAG(self.count, 1).over(order_by=[self.date])
).alias('diff')
```

and NOT "factored-out" like this:

```
(fn.LAG(self.count, 0) - fn.LAG(self.count, 1)
   .over(order_by=[self.date])
).alias('diff')
```

What had me confused me was that this code DOES works even though the wondow is "factored-out":

```
return (self.count - fn.LAG(self.count, 1)
   .over(order_by=[self.date])
).alias('diff')
```

I fixed the original code above and it now generates the expected output.

Comment: You can't call `fn.LAG(self.count, 0)` by itself, it has no meaning. You need a window. The 2nd instance has that (over date) which is why it works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment  but the way I tested this code was by commenting-out one of the two return statements at a time so that the ".over(order_by=[self.date])" clause was in effect in both runs.

Comment: I should also mention that the code fails when the FIRST return statement is commented-out.

Comment: Carles, after your comment I looked at the code again and was able to fix the problem. Thanks!